# How to loop through a series of ID numbers in a json

Tags: python, json, loops

I am trying to pull certain data from a json. There is a list of ID numbers and information I want to pull out of each ID number, but I am unsure how to do this.[Image shows the structure of the json, it is the players ID that I want to loop through to pull further information from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mqMK.png).

[information inside the player ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7PF5.png)

Im looking for a list of times with no connection to one another.

```
toi = []

for i in range(len(game_data_1)):
    for j in range(len(game_data_1[i]['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['home']['players'])):
        toi.append(j['stats']['skaterStats']['timeOnIce'])
```

game_data_1 is the name of the json. My hope was to loop through each player ID to get to the stat that I was looking for, in this case timeOnIce. However I get the error "'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: How did you attempt to find out what `int` the error is referring to?

Comment: `j` is an integer, it isn't the object you are looking for. `for i in range(len(something)): something[i]` is not a Pythonic way to loop through `something`, just use `for i in something: i`. Just use `for i in game_data_1: for j in game_data[blah]: j[blah]`. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Do you want a single total time for all players and games or some other total grouped by some combination of player and game or do you just want a list of times with no connection to player or game. Please update your question with some example results you hope for.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at explaining myself. Im looking for a list of times, connected to each player and game. But since I was stuck at this point I was trying to get this before adding in the other steps. I have been able to get that information before, I'm just struggling with going through each player by the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments `j` is an integer representing the position in the list during the loop. Not the players data, You could store the player data in a variable and then access the time on ice using `j`:

```
toi = []

for i in range(len(game_data_1)):
    players = game_data_1[i]['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['home']['players']
    for j in range(len(players)):
        toi.append(players[j]['stats']['skaterStats']['timeOnIce'])
```

And even better not even use range and just loop over the actual data:

```
for game in game_data_1:
    for player in game['liveData']['boxscore']['teams']['home']['players'])):
        toi.append(player['stats']['skaterStats']['timeOnIce'])
```